# Time complexity of reverseOrder method of Collection

Tags: java, collections

I have a list of files which I want to sort based on last access time in descending order. What's the better way out of below 2 ways:

1. Write a custom comparator which has logic for comparing in reverse order
2. Write a customer comparator which has logic for comparing in ascending order and then call `Comparator.reversed()` in caller method

I prefer #1 because `reversed()` will again take O(n) time where n is equal to the size of list. 
I would like to know opinions of folks here.

Comment: Do you mean "reverse the collection after sorting" with `Comparator.reversed()`?

Comment: @Clashsoft:   yes. I mean Comparator.reversed().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `Comparator.reversed()` does is to reverse order of arguments by creating a new wrapper object for target `Comparator` that sorts in natural order. Instead of `(a, b)` it compares `(b, a)`. It **doesn't** reverse the list as a last step after the natual order sort.

The cost of sorting the list will be the same. If your data is large and already pre-sorted the sort direction will matter but for small collections it makes no practical difference.

Comment: Yes, my data is large. So what do you recommend? Should I write the logic in custom comparator to sort in reverse order or sort in natural order and then apply reversed method. What's the time complexity of reversed()?

Comment: Write code which is idiomatic and clear to read. I'd go for `reversed()`. If the performance is not acceptable write a JMH microbenchmark to prove that writing a custom comparator improves the performance. The big question would be what is your data and how are you loading it.

Comment: @Priyanka reversed() itself has the same time complexity as the comparator is was called on (so probably O(1)). It has does not reverse the list, it changes the sort order so it comes out reversed after sorting, but thats not an extra step.

Comment: The reference implementation uses TimSort, which can deal very well with presorted data, including the case that the data is presorted into the opposite direction. The costs for sorting the entire list are `O(n)` in this case.